# Image on WindowsForm != TextRenderer.DrawText() image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557513/why-is-it-not-possible-to-save-any-font-as-image-but-to-display-it-on-my-windo), I was able to display some special fonts on my WindowsForm **but** I was not able to save this font as picture. The problem was that `Graphic.DrawString()` is not able to display all or special fonts. WindowsForm is using `TextRenderer` and its newer (added with 2.0) thats why WindowsForm was able to display these fonts.

Fine. Now Im sitting here and trying to do the same stuff with `TextRenderer.DrawText()` - I have to say that my output image is now much better **but** still not the same as on the WindowsForm. Lets look at my code:

```
    Bitmap Bit = new Bitmap(500, 200);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bit);

    string s = "TEST";

    g.Clear(Color.White);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, s, new Font("Code 128", 72), new Point(20, 20), Color.Black, Color.White);
    Bit.Save(@"C:\myFolder\test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    Bit.Dispose();
```

(Code 128 is a special font, if you really want to know more about it just klick on the link below for more information)

So this is working, I get my image, fine. Now Im adding the same string with the same font on the same VS Project as Label on my WindowsForm. And there is some difference. The difference is that the image created with `TextRenderer` got always a different character at the first position. Everything else is fine! I dont get it. Lets have a look WinForm VS Image:

[image: WindowsForm with Label VS TextRenderer Image (same string and the font)]

As we can see the first "character" (if we can say 'character' for this example) is somehow not the same. Now let me change my string in my TextRenderer Image function to "TTEST". Compare "TEST" on WinForm with "TTEST" on TextRenderer Image:

[image]

Looks interesting right? So, `TextRenderer.DrawText()` + special font = first char is weird. But why? And how to fix this? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Edit: If it helps I can post the Code of the WindowsForm

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Code 128", 72F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(2)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 41);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 94);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "TEST";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

As we see its the same font, with the same string. I dont get it...

Comment: Where are you getting this bitmap that you're comparing to?

Comment: @CodyGray Im getting the bitmap with my code - its posted there - Im saving it as test.bmp and at the same time a windowsform with my label is coming up (same project). So thats how I can compare these 2 "images".

Comment: Have you tried to use the TextFormatFlags parameter for some TextRenderer.DrawText overloads?

Comment: @SimonMourier I did, some of them. It changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You posted the wrong code, it is the bitmap version that's off.  Looks like UEST to me, a conspicuous off-by-one error.

That's not the only problem, even if you'd fix this it still isn't a valid Code128 barcode.  You also need the Start, Check and Stop character, as documented in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Specification).  You are possibly close to the inevitable "buy, don't build" conclusion.  Finding controls that generate barcodes isn't difficult or expensive.

Comment: Hi. Why is this the wrong code? In the first Codeblock Im using TextRenderer, in the second one (windowsform + label). In both case its the same string and the same font, but the fist "character" is always different. And please lets dont talk about the "valid barcode". I know how to generate the checksum and know what start and stop character I need there. But even if I use the right characters, again: TextRenderer wont "render" the first char correct.

Comment: If I create just a label and using Label.DrawToBitmap() it is fine too. I dont really get it. I startet another thread with a new example  @ms forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/2448c9f1-2836-4c9f-bc2a-704858139994

Comment: I can confirm the OP's findings and I don't think you are right here. The TextRenderer does mess up things and DrawString as well as a Label get it as right as the Font used will go. Somebody somewhere mentioned that TextFormatFlags should be used on the DrawText call, but would not reveal which. - The matter of having to add the control codes is not related to the issue of TextRenderer messing up the start of the output..